# Is there any Logical Volume Manager solution exist that supports Ubuntu and Windows both Operating System?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, lvm, storage

I know there exist Logical Volume Manager like "LVM" for Ubuntu or "Storage Space" for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 (I am only given example here, there may exist multiple similar solutions for the individual platform).

But I want to know if there any solution exist that supports both Operating Systems 
for dual-booting Windows 10 + Ubuntu, with all the goodies from General Logical Volume Manager.

Comment: This is a general computing question, so how did you decide to ask it here instead of using your Super User account? Super User is where to ask questions about both platforms.

Comment: I have edited my question, actually, I want to know the technical aspect of the said question.